Examine whether the equilibrium is stable or unstable
I need help for an
exercise. For the differential equation $x'= \alpha x^3$, I need to examine whether the equilibrium is stable, asymptotically stable or unstable. I know how to do this sort of task when given a system of the form $(x', y') = (\ldots, \ldots)$, but I don‘ t know how to do it here. Can you please help me ?
Thanks.

The equilibrium for this equation is x*=0

Examine the system $(x',y')=(\alpha x^3, \alpha y^3)$.

I did. For alpha =0 all eigenvalues are zero, for alpha>0 there is a positive eigenvalue and another one equal to zero, for alpha<0 a negative eigenvalue and an eigenvalue that is zero. the case alpha> 0 means instability. But what use is this to me now?

Just draw the phase portrait! (For the original 1-dimensional equation; bringing in a 2-dimensional system is just making things more complicated. By the way, you must have made a mistake in your calculations. The Jacobian of your system at the origin is the zero matrix, so both eigenvalues are zero, and linearization tells you nothing.)

@Moo I drew a phase portrait
